# To whom did the bifocals belong to in the movie Chinatown?

Tags: plot-explanation, chinatown

In the 1974 movie *Chinatown* the following happens:

> At Evelyn's mansion, Gittes finds her servants packing her things. He realizes her garden pond is salt water and discovers a pair of bifocals in it. He confronts Evelyn about her "sister"; after Gittes slaps her, she admits that the woman, Katherine, is her sister and her daughter: her father raped her when she was fifteen. *She says that the eyeglasses are not Mulwray's, as he did not wear bifocals*.
>   [Wikipedia-Chinatown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinatown_%281974_film%29)

As the bifocals were not belonging to Mulwray, why did Gittes accuse Cross of murdering Mulwray in the salt water and leaving the bifocals in the pond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Gittes concludes that they're Noah Cross's.** From the script:

> **GITTES:** An obituary column... can you read in this light?
>
> **CROSS:** Yes... I think I can manage...
>
> *Cross dips into his coat pocket and **pulls out a pair of rimless glasses.. He puts them on, reads. Gittes stares at the bifocal lenses** as Cross continues to look through the obituary column. He looks up.*
>
> **CROSS:** What does this mean?
>
> **GITTES:** -- that you killed Hollis Mulwray --
>
> *Gittes is holding the bifocals with the broken lens now.*
>
> **GITTES:** (continuing) -- right here, in this pond. You drowned him... and you left *these*.

And since Noah takes them away from him as to not incriminate himself, Gittes is probably right.